# Checking for alphanumeric values with asp:RegularExpressionValidator alwas shows ErrorMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want a user to only input numbers and letters. I use the `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`with the following `ValidationExpression`: `[^A-Za-z0-9]`
Here is my full control:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidatorUserName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Check your input!" ControlToValidate="tb_userName" ValidationExpression="[^A-Za-z0-9]"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

When I insert something into my textbox the ErrorMessage is always shown. 
How can I fix this problem or do I need another markup for the ValidationExpression?

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9]*$`.

Comment: What does `*$` mean?

Comment: `*` is a quantifier matching *0 or more symbols satisfying the preceding subpattern*, and `$` is the end of string. I think in your case (as the attribute is anchored) you can use `[A-Za-z0-9]*`. But if you want to require at least 1 character, you need to use `+` quantifier, like in the accepted answer.

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9]+` will also accept zero characters within a `RegularExpressionValidator `, for that case you need a `RequiredFieldValidator` additionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches a single character not in a-z, A-Z, 0-9 which doesn't sound like what you want.

I think you want:

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Za-z0-9]+"
```

which is one or more characters in a-z, A-Z, 0-9